# Add a space in between loop outputs using .format: Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, format

I am trying to create a for loop where the user inputs a number n and the output provides the range of values from n to n+6. This needs to all be printed in one row and be right aligned with spaces in between value outputs but **no space at the end or start** of the output.

So far this is what I've come up with:

```
n=eval(input("Enter the start number: "))
for n in range(n,n+7):
  print("{0:>2}".format(n),end=" ")
```

However, this results in the following output:

```
-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4 <EOL>
```

When the output I want needs to look similar but **without** the space at the end, like so:

```
-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4<EOL>
```

How can I add spaces between values without adding an additional space to the final term?

Comment: *without the space at the end*. So just use `end=""` instead of `end= " "` also don't use `eval` directly on users input. Instead use `int`.

Comment: I've tried that, but using end="" results in there being no space between negative values like so:

-2-1 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: Yes, that's because of the `for` loop. You can `join` your range with space. `" ".join(map(str, range(n,n+7)))`. Using `map` and `str` will convert the integer numbers to string so that the're valid types for `join`. or `' '.join([{0:>2}".format(i) for i in range(n, n+ 7)])`

Comment: Or you could use `print`'s `sep` argument: `print(*map("{0:>2}".format, range(n, n + 7)), sep=' ')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 recommendations I could make:

1. use `end=""` and insert the whitespaces manually
2. create a string and print after the loop:

   ```
   s = ""
   for n in range(n, n+7):
       s+= str(n)+ " "
   s = s[:-1] #remove the ending whitespace
   print(s)
   ```
3. which I recommend: Using sys.stdout.write instead print:
   print only displays the message after a linebreak was printed. So if there is a long calculation in the loop and there is `end=" "` you will only see the resulr at the end of all calculations. Use sys.stdout instead

   ```
   for n in range(n, n+7):
       if n < n+7:
           sys.stdout.write(str(n)+" ")
       else:
           sys.stdout.write(str(n))
       sys.stdour.flush() #flush output to console
   ```

Edit: I evolved a bit and this is what I'd use nowadays:
4. message = " ".join(range(n, n+7))
This puts spaces between all elements of a list. You can choose any separation character instead of a space (or multiple characters).

Comment: Sorry. I can't get the code formatting to work properly. I hope you can use it anyway

Comment: Heyo, your second method is a great workaround thanks!

Comment: Hey, no problem. I'm glad I could help you ;-)

Comment: Hi... just for completeness: I added my preferred fourth method. Though it would be time for this after more than 2 years. ;)